# Add Font Awesome icon through JS

Tags: jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I'm building JQM app using Font Awesome icons and all is fine if I add into HTML `<i class=icon-XXX></i>`. The problem appears if I create it through javascript. It never appears!

This icon is into a `<ul /><li />`and I've tried triggering "refresh", "create", ... but nothing happens.

Is there anyway to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Regards,

PS. I'm using bootstrap also and I load first bootstrap and then FA as says in FA webpage...

**UPDATE** (Easy code...)

**JS**

```
var elemHtml = "" +
"<div data-type=\"tlf\" id=\"XXX\">
    <ul data-role=\"listview\" data-inset=\"true\" data-theme=\""+selectedTheme+"\">
        <li data-icon=\"false\">
            <a href=\"tel:600123456\"><i class=\"icon-phone\"></i>600123456</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>";

$("#screen").contents().find("#screenBody").append(elemHtml);
```

**JSP**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="screen">
    <div id="screenBody"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: try after appending the elements. `$("#screenBody").find("a").addClass("icon-phone");`

Comment: Thank you @Omar but it doesn't work. I've tried initializing `.listview()` and then adding `<li>` + `.listview("resfresh")` and nothing.

Comment: if you referesh the page manually, does the icons appear?

Comment: sorry, i meant `$("#screenBody").find("i").addClass("icon-phone");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did test the below code and it works normally, using Font-Awesome (without Bootstrap.js). I also gave the `listview` an ID (`#listviewtest`).

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
 var elemHtml = 
  "<div data-type='tlf'>"
  + "<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='' id='listviewtest'>"
   + "<li data-icon='false'><a href='tel:600123456'>"
   + "<i class='icon-phone'></i>600123456</a>"
   + "</li>"
   + "<li data-icon='false'><a href='tel:600123456'>"
   + "<i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>600123456</a>"
   + "</li>"
  + "</ul>"
  + "</div>";
 $("div[data-role='content']").append(elemHtml); // append to data-role='content'
 $('#listviewtest').listview();
});
```